# Continuous (sinc) Wavelet Transform gives NaN

Tags: fortran

```
  implicit     none
  character*20 fflname,oflname
  integer      length_sgnl
  real*8       pi, dt, m, n, theta
  parameter    ( length_sgnl=11900, dt=0.01d0, m=1, n=1, pi=3.1416
 &            ,theta=0.2 )

  integer      i     
  complex*16   cj, coeff ,sgnl(1 : length_sgnl)
  real*8       t(1 : length_sgnl)
  parameter    ( cj = dcmplx(0, 1) )

  real*8       time, real_sgnl, imag_sgnl


  oflname="filtered.data"
  fflname="artificial"
  open(11, file = oflname)
  do i=1, length_sgnl
     read(11, *) time, real_sgnl, imag_sgnl
     sgnl(i) = dcmplx(real_sgnl, imag_sgnl)
     t(i) = (i*dt - m) / (2**n)
  enddo

  coeff = 0
  do i=1, length_sgnl
     coeff = coeff 
 &        + sgnl(i) * sin(pi*t(i)) / (pi*t(i)) * exp (-cj*2*pi*t(i))
  enddo


  do i=1, length_sgnl
     sgnl(i) = sgnl(i) 
 &         - coeff * sin(pi*t(i)) / (pi*t(i)) * exp (-cj*2*pi*t(i))
 &         + coeff * sin(pi*t(i)) / (pi*t(i)) * exp (-cj*2*pi*t(i))
 &         * exp (cj*theta)
  enddo

  open(12, file = fflname)
  do i=1, length_sgnl
    write(12, *) i*dt, sgnl(i)
  enddo
  close(12)

  stop
  end
```

---

I want to give a phase shift to the original signal by continuous Shannon wavelet transform.
The result of constructed signal is all NaN although it is compiled without any error message.

Comment: You are probably dividing by zero somewhere. Compile with all debugging flags and enable floating point exceptions and you willl find the spot.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your comment makes sense and helps.

Comment: sinc(x) = sin( pi * t ) / ( pi * t ) tends to 1 as t -> 0, but this gives floating-point exception (division by zero) when t is 0.0d0 (numerically). This happens for t(i) = (i*dt - m) / (2**n) because dt = 0.01d0 and i and m are integers. So... maybe better to write a custom sinc() function that treats t = 0 exceptionally? (e.g., if ( abs(t) < 1.0d-6 ) ... else ... ).